# How to implement repeating questions in Access 2007 forms?

Tags: microsoft-access-2007

I want to repeat questions in a fillable form containing:

- Name, Address
- Name, Address
- Name, Address
- ...

Access says I can't repeat entries. I am trying to make a list of persons.

Comment: is this an Access 2007 form? you need a 'continuous' form to do that.  if this is a web form? then what are you using for that? Asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

click on the table with the two fields (name and address)
[image]

click on the "Multiple Items" button
[image]

click on the form view and start entering away
[image]